# Get GeckoFx firefox browser control iframe html not accessible

Tags: c#, iframe, geckofx

I am using the GeckoFX 22 c# web browser control but cannot manage to access tags within an iframe.  When I check the gecko innerhtml it seems that although the iframe tag shows in the html, the contents of it do not.

This is the code I used to get the inner html of the browser control which just shows the iframe tag as empty (when it should have another  doc inside of it):

```
        GeckoHtmlElement element = null;
            var geckoDomElement = webBrowser.Document.DocumentElement;
            if (geckoDomElement is GeckoHtmlElement)
            {
                element = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoDomElement;
                var innerHtml = element.InnerHtml;
            }
```

Previously I used code similar to the code below to access individual elements which works fine:

```
GeckoDocument checkDoc = (GeckoDocument)webBrowser.Window.Document;
var x = (checkDoc.GetElementsByTagName("a").Where(b => b.Id == "ipt-form-format-aside").First());
```

I am able to get individual elements and change their values/trigger events etc without problems with the main html document but anything in an iframe is impossible to get the elements of. I think perhaps the Iframe has not been loaded yet or something like that.  Is there a way to force the control to wait for the I frame to load before attempting to access its elements?

Comment: no answer here is working. same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243259/get-recaptcha2-iframe-html-but-always-empty-using-geckofx-browser-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

```
string content = null;
var iframe = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe").FirstOrDefault() as Gecko.DOM.GeckoIFrameElement;
if(iframe != null)
{
    var html = iframe.ContentDocument.DocumentElement as GeckoHtmlElement;
    if (html != null)
        content = html.OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, the iframe had not fully loaded when trying to access the elements.  Eventually I used another approach and did not need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting this for anyone else that might get this problem

```
foreach (GeckoIFrameElement _E in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe"))
{
    if (_E.GetAttribute("class") == "testClass")
    {
        var innerHTML = _E.ContentDocument;

        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement _A in innerHTML.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            _A.SetAttribute("value", "Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem so i did this

```
checkDoc.Window.Frames(1)
```

instead of

```
checkDoc.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
```

value within the parenthesis (i.e. 1 here) depends of your index