# Get Recaptcha2 Iframe HTML but always EMPTY using GeckoFX Browser in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, iframe, captcha, recaptcha, geckofx

I am using the latest GeckoFX-45 Browser for vb.net.

My problem:
I can not get the HTML of the Iframe.

Here is my code:

```
'Open Recaptcha2 test site
Browser.Navigate("http://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/")
'Wait for loading (all ways I know)
Browser.NavigateFinishedNotifier.BlockUntilNavigationFinished()
Dim maxTimeouttime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4)
While DateTime.Now < maxTimeouttime
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End While
While Browser.IsBusy()
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End While   

'Getting the HTML of the Iframe is always empty:
For Each _E As GeckoIFrameElement In Browser.DomDocument.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
If _E.GetAttribute("title") = "recaptcha widget" Then
Dim html = _E.ContentDocument '-> is empty  
Dim html2  = _E.OuterHtml '-> HTML does not include the content of the Iframe 
Exit For
End If
Next
```

The site is displayed very well in the Browser and the recaptcha2 iframe is loaded completly and ready but how can I access it programatically?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `ContentWindow.Document` instead of `ContentDocument`.
Your code shoud be:

```
Dim iFr_dom As GeckoDomDocument
Dim iFr_html As String
For Each iFr As GeckoIFrameElement In Browser.DomDocument.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
    If iFr.GetAttribute("title") = "recaptcha widget" Then
        iFr_dom = iFr.ContentWindow.Document

        'DomDocument has no OuterHtml property so we use
        iFr_html = iFr_dom.GetElementsByTagName("BODY")(0).OuterHtml
        'Or if the above not work, use the code below
        'iFr_html = iFr_doc.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).OuterHtml
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```